# Inserting Data Into Cassandra table Using Spark DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm using Scala Version 2.10.5 Cassandra 3.0 and Spark 1.6. I want to insert data into cassandra so I tried Out basic Example

```
scala> val collection = sc.parallelize(Seq(("cat", 30), ("fox", 40)))
scala> collection.saveToCassandra("test", "words", SomeColumns("word", "count"))
```

Which Works and able insert data into Cassandra.So I had a csv file Which I wan to insert into Cassandra table by matching schema

```
val person = sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hduser/person")
import org.apache.spark.sql._
val schema =  StructType(Array(StructField("firstName",StringType,true),StructField("lastName",StringType,true),StructField("age",IntegerType,true)))
val rowRDD = person.map(_.split(",")).map(p =&gt; org.apache.spark.sql.Row(p(0),p(1),p(2).toInt))
val personSchemaRDD = sqlContext.applySchema(rowRDD, schema)
 personSchemaRDD.saveToCassandra
```

When I am using SaveToCassndra Iam getting saveToCassandra is not part of personSchemaRDD. So taught of trying in different way

```
 df.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(Map( "table" -> "words_copy", "keyspace" -> "test")).save()
```

But getting the cannot connect to cassandra on ip:port.can any one tell me the best way to do it. I need to periodically save data to cassandra from the files.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`sqlContext.applySchema(...)` returns a `DataFrame` and a `DataFrame` does not have the `saveToCassandra` method.

You could the `.write` method with it:

```
val personDF = sqlContext.applySchema(rowRDD, schema)
personDF.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(Map( "table" -> "words_copy", "keyspace" -> "test")).save()
```

If we want to use the `savetoCassandra`  method, the best way is to have a  schema-aware RDD, using a case class.

```
case class Person(firstname:String, lastName:String, age:Int)
val rowRDD = person.map(_.split(",")).map(p => Person(p(0),p(1),p(2).toInt)
rowRDD.saveToCassandra(keyspace, table)
```

The Dataframe `write` method should work. Check that you have configured your context correctly.

Comment: How can I convert one of the element in Row() to                                    `val rowRDD = input.map(_.split(",")).map(p => Row( p(0),getTimestamp((1)), p(2)))                                                                 I want to YYYY-MM-DD' 'HH:mm:ss format

Comment: @Anji you would be better off by mapping timestamps to `java.util.Date` of `jodatime.DateTime` to avoid format issues.

Comment: When Using com.databricks.spark.csv is there any option to take "NA" my error `Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable number: "NA"`

Comment: @Anji Don't drag questions in the comments. If you have a new issue, consider asking a new question.

Comment: It worked it's a connection issue changed in cassandta.yaml subnet_address

Comment: Where are you connecting to Cassandra ? i have df from oracle , now i have to save to cassandra , how should i get the connection , using which i need to save

Answer (score 0):

I am putting my code here to save Spark dataset into Cassandra table using Spark Java.

```
private static void readBigEmptable(SparkSession sparkSession) {
   String cassandraEmpColumns= "id,name,salary,age,city";
    Dataset<Row> bigDataset = sparkSession.sql("select * from big_emp");
    // Generate the schema for output row
    List<StructField> fields = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String fieldName : cassandraEmpColumns.split(",")) {
        StructField field = DataTypes.createStructField(fieldName, DataTypes.StringType, true);
        fields.add(field);
    }
    StructType schemaStructure = DataTypes.createStructType(fields);
    // Converting big dataset to RDD to perform operation on Row field
    JavaRDD<Row> bigRDD = bigDataset.toJavaRDD();
    JavaRDD<Row> resultRDD = bigRDD .map(new Function<Row, Row>() {

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Row call(Row row) throws Exception {
            // return compareField(row).iterator();
            Row outputRow = RowFactory.create(row.getAs("id"), row.getAs("name"), row.getAs("salary"),
                    row.getAs("age"), row.getAs("city"));
            return outputRow;
        }
    });
    Dataset<Row> empDs = sparkSession.createDataFrame(resultRDD, schemaStructure);
    empDs.show();
    writeToCassandraTable(empDs);

}

private static void writeToCassandraTable(Dataset<Row> dataset) {
    Map<String, String> tableProperties = new HashMap();
    tableProperties.put("keyspace", "test_keyspace");
    tableProperties.put("table", "emp_test");
    tableProperties.put("confirm.truncate", "true");
    dataset.write().format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(tableProperties).mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
            .save();
}
```

**Note:** If we are using *mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)* then we should use *tableProperties.put("confirm.truncate", "true");* otherwise we will get error message.

**SaveMode.Append**

- Append mode means that when saving a DataFrame to a data    source,
  if data/table already exists, contents of the DataFrame are  expected
  to be appended to existing data.

**SaveMode.ErrorIfExists**

- ErrorIfExists mode means that when saving a DataFrame to a data
  source, if data already exists, an exception is expected to be
  thrown.

**SaveMode.Ignore**

- Ignore mode means that when saving a DataFrame to a data source, if data already exists, the save operation is expected to not save the contents of the DataFrame and to not change the existing data.

**SaveMode.Overwrite**

- Overwrite mode means that when saving a DataFrame to a data source,
  if data/table already exists, existing data is expected to be
  overwritten by the contents of the DataFrame.